# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm getting this error for my **SQLite** database in Android app. This is the first time I'm having an issue with this error so I need help.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  String CREATE_WE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME +
                "("+ Constants.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " +
                Constants.JOB_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + Constants.JOB_DESCRIPTION +
                " TEXT NOT NULL , " + Constants.START_YEAR + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
                Constants.END_YEAR + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

  db.execSQL(CREATE_WE_TABLE);
}
```

And my error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE workexperience(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , title TEXT NOT NULL , description TEXT NOT NULL , 1 TEXT NOT NULL , 1 TEXT NOT NULL);
```

What seems to be a problem?

Comment: put some `String` instead of `int` number `Constants.START_YEAR`

Comment: check value for  Constants.START_YEAR and Constants.END_YEAR inside your Constants

Comment: After description (in your query), you have `START_YEAR` and `END_YEAR` and both are the integer number one. You can't have a column named `1`. You especially can't have two columns named `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print your create table statement. its clearly says that syntax is not correct. Correct the syntax then it will work fine.

EDIT: as in comment section suggested you cant have column two column name as 1. please change it to work.